# Is there a name for someone who owes a debt?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm currently writing fiction about a firm that collects debt from citizens who owe money to various places, such as banks, or government agencies (involving government loans or unpaid taxes). Is there a word to describe someone who owes a debt, specifically money, or does it vary depending on where the money is owed to? If a person who collects debt is a debt collector, perhaps a debt collectee?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We call that person a "debtor." (You can use this with companies too).

And I think you should use "creditor" for the other person.

Comment: Actually, the firm she is writing about would be called a *Collections Agency.*" They typically provide collection services to the actual creditor for some percentage of the amount collected- either by buying the debt outright at a discount or through a collections contract.

Answer (score 8):

The word you're looking for is *debtor*.

Answer (score 0):

Beside *debtor*, you could use *borrower* and in case of mortgages *mortgager*.